# Replace true/false to diffrent text or check marks in specific listview and specific column

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got `listview` as shown below. I am looking for a way to somehow instead of `true/false` show some other `text` or place `check marks` instead. How can i achieve that?

**Important remark:** I have many pages with diffrent listviews where also true/false appears. I would like to be able to choose for which listview that solution be defined and the best that i could choose specific listview and column (if possible of course)

asdasdasd

[image]

**Specific part where True/False values are placed (BottleIsFilled):**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0"
                              
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding BottleTypeName}" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                              
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding BottleIsFilled}" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="2"
                              
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                           </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: use BoolToObjectConverter - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/booltoobjectconverter

Comment: @Jason <xct:BoolToObjectConverter i get error that this was not found

Comment: please take the time to read the docs -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/get-started

Comment: @Jason That works ! Nevertheless in Error list i got:  Type xct:BoolToObjectConverter not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit

Comment: try using `xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Converters;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"`

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Converters/BoolToObjectConverterPage.xaml

Comment: @Jason Funny thing is this was added automaticly by nugget. Nevertheless i restarted Visual Studio and error dissapered :). Additional question: instead of text can i somehow put there check markup?

Comment: I believe you can to use a glyph with a font icon for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason suggested use `BoolToObjectConverter` from [XamarinCommunityToolkit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit)

1. Install the nuget package on all your projects (shared and platform).
2. Add the xaml namespace for this package `xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"`
3. Instantiate and consume BoolToObjectConverter

Seems one common instance for each page is appropriate for your use case.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
      <xct:BoolToObjectConverter x:Name="BoolToObjectConverter" TrueObject="yes" FalseObject="no"/>

</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding BottleIsFilled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToObjectConverter}}"/>
```

#### Docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/booltoobjectconverter

#### Note

If you got error about the namespace, try typing `<BoolToObjectConverter />` and put cursor on it, on vs intelisense should highlight it and suggest and apply the correct namespace for you when you click "ctrl+." Or ctrl+enter.

Comment: Thanks this works, additional question is can i instead of text put there check mark?

Comment: if you want a checkmark you can just use an image and bind it's IsVisible property directly to the bool without using a converter

Comment: Agree with Jason unless you want to display a cross when it's false, then it's another story

Comment: Thanks guys you both, i will check later on !